# Redirect from one servlet to another from the servler doGet() method using <a href="">

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, redirect

Hi I have a question how to redirect from starting servlet body(doGet() or doPost()) to another's servlet site?

First servlet:

```
public class StartingServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("Strona startowa");
//      String go  ="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/test";        
//      response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(go));
        out.println("<a href=”http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/test”> Hello World Servlet </a>");
    }

}
```

Second servlet(the one that i want to go after i click on link):

```
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World Servlet");

    }
}
```

web.xml file(servlet-mappings url-pattern for the starting servlet is empty on purpose):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Starting servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.javastart.servlets.StartingServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Starting servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello World Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.javastart.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello World Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

How do I do that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To redirect a request from servlet you can use `sendRedirect` method :

```
    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/test");
```

Btw this statement:

```
out.println("<a href=”http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/test”> Hello World Servlet </a>");
```

will simply send the link in response body but will not redirect.

Comment: I've used that method (sendRedirect()) but it goes directly to that site, and I can't even see the site from Starting Servlet

Answer (score 0):

You can link one servlet to another using href as :

```
<a href="servletURL?param=value">click here</a>
```

Here servletURL is written as "/nameofproject/urlpattern?"

Other method is getRequestDispatcher which will pass the values also to other servlet/jsp file etc.

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/xyz.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Hope that helps.